# SQL Update a set of records based on change in one field

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the example set of data:

```
seq  id    status in_process processed 
3    A     N      T          F
```

This is a mockup of a staging table I'm using on a schedule. It's fairly more complex, but I hope this is enough to get the point across.

Processing of this record occurs every 15 minutes. For a given "id", the records are handled in order of seq from lowest to highest. If status = 'N' (new), the record will be processed. If the above record is encountered at this the time it is run, the id data will get processed and processed will be updated to 'T'

Later if the below is encountered...

```
seq  id    status in_process processed
5    A     D      T          F
```

The id will be processed and the destination will be informed of the new status = 'D' (deleted), processed will be updated to 'T'

But if instead, the following happens between runs:

```
seq  id    status in_process processed
5    A     D      T          F 
3    A     N      T          F
```

I want no processing to occur and to simply update processed to 'T'

Given the last scenario, what update query can I use? I want to essentially say

```
update myTable set processed = 'T' where {processed = 'F' and status was N and is now D for a given id}
```

It's that last part in curly brackets that I'm not sure how to write. Since the same id won't have a status of N after a status of D, I don't necessarilly need to reference the seq value, so long as status = 'N' and processed = 'F' for the same id I plan to update. For more example, in the below example, I'd want to update id A and D1 without processing and leave B and C records alone with the update.

```
seq  id    status in_process processed
8    D1    D      T          F
7    D1    N      T          F
6    C     D      T          F
5    A     D      T          F 
4    B     N      T          F
3    A     N      T          F
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is similar to another problem I posted here a little while ago and wondering if the following can be tweeked. I think this would work if I was only worried about two states (N and D), but I also have A to worry about. If D is encountered before N is processed, then the A should be marked as processed as well..

`update myTable set processed = 'T', in_process = 'T' where status = 'D' and processed = 'F' and (seq, id) in (select seq, id from myTable where status = 'N' and processed = 'F')`

Comment: I realize that the above update wouldn't work for the scenario of just N and D statuses either... any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT`-Trigger which controls whether a new record shall be inserted or an existing one shall be updated.

As an `INSTEAD OF INSERT`-Trigger in Oracle can be defined only for views (and not for tables), one would have to do the following:

1. Rename you table into `staging_data` and create a view `staging`,
   e.g. as `create view staging as (select * from staging_data)`.
   Thereby, your application will insert forth on into the view and
   will trigger your specific code.
2. In the trigger code, use `:new`-attributes and `select`-statements
       on the underlying data table `staging_data` to identify whether an
       update or an insert shall be performed.
3. Finally, perform the insert or update.

Unfortunately I do not have an environment to write the trigger and try it out; Hope it helps though. Confer, for example, SO answer [Oracle view not updatable, advice on Instead Of triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5260872/2630032) or consult google.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Unfortunately, the environment I'm working in is a little more limited where we are trying to limit database-side objects. Can you tell me if this update would have any issues? (forgive my frequent accidental enters) `update myTable set in_process = 'T', processed = 'T' where seq in (select distinct(a.seq) 
from myTable a
inner join (select id from myTable where status = 'N' and processed = 'F') b on a.id = b.id
inner join (select id from myTable where status = 'D' and processed = 'F') b on a.id = c.id
where a.procesed = 'F';`

Comment: Hard to say without trying out; I don't see any obvious issue (in oracle; other databases do not allow to use the table to be updated also in a from part on the subqueries. But besides updates you will also have to remove the extra tuple having appeared between the runs, right?

Comment: The query seems to work fine. I needed it to cover this specific case or would've had to write a loop in code to process this. The other cases will be processed within code as they need to pull in values out of context.  Thanks again for your time and info on the instead of triggers. :)